# Recurring background task Android - Handler vs AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, android-handler

I am working on an application for research purposes. We want to track some user activity on the phone: if some actions are easily detactable with broadcast receivers, we want also to check current running applications.
This application works only on Android devices that runs android 5.0 or lower.

My problem is that I post a Runnable Obj in a handler, Runnable posts again itself in handler after HALF_SECOND (see code for details). In runnable I get information and send them to IntentService to perform work.

Everything works fine: app starts at boot, handler and runnable do their job in background UNLESS I open the main Activity.
The app is able to keep going for days, but if I open the main Activity and then close it from "recent open activities" with a swipe, or from the memory task manager, handler and runnable stop, even if they are not called/accessed by the activity (they are in a Separate Service).
Moreover, not always a call to onDestroy (of the activity or Service) is made.
Reading online I understand that swipe or task manager remove the app from memory abrouptly thus not always calling onDestory.

What I want to achive is to make the handler start again soon after the main activity is closed.

What I have tried is to put some check in onPause method of the activity, making sure to remove this check if onStart is called again (like in case the the app switches from vertical to horizontal layout, or if home button is pressed and then app is opend again). Also implemented a way to make the handler send "ImAlive" intent to a broadcast receiver, which should restart the service that starts the handler, if intents do not arrive before a count down is finished. Unfortunately, as soon the main activty stops existing, even the broadcast is automatically unregistered and destroyed.

My question is, is there a way to create something that is able to make my handler restart if the activity is closed? Or is there some other pattern that can help me as workaround for what I want to achieve? Because I am polling data every half second I read is better to use handler, because Timer augments small interval to a greater interval, and AlarmManager is not precise enough for very small interval.

What I want to achieve is something similar to Facebook, Instagram, Whatsapp, Telegram app, that are always in memory, and even if you force to terminate them, after a few seconds are back again there... how?

We are not interested in battery issues because of continuous polling to data. As for research purposes we don't mind if the phone on which we are testing last 2 days straight, 1 day or 12 hours or less.

Here the code: OnBootService is started from broadcast receiver, declared in manifest when onBootCompleted and ShutDown actions are received, in order to start and stop handler.

```
public class OnBootService extends Service{
    private static final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final long HALF_SEC = 500;
    private RunnableTest r = null;
    private Context myContext = this;
    private final String TAG = "BootService";
    // Extras
    public static final String START = "start";
    public static final String STOP = "stop";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId){

        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch(action){
            case START: startHandler();
                break;
            case STOP: stopHandler();
                break;
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startHandler(){
        if(r == null){
            r = new RunnableTest();

            handler.post(r);
            Log.i(TAG, "----Handler started!");
        }

    }

    private void stopHandler(){    
        if(r != null){
            Log.i(TAG, "----calling STOP");
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            r = null;
        }

    }

    private class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
        private String TAG = "RunnableTest";

        public RunnableTest(){}

        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);

            // Do stuff
            Intent i = new Intent(myContext, MyIntentService.class);
            i.putExtra("addStuff", myStuff);
            myContext.startService(i);

            handler.postDelayed(this, HALF_SEC);
        }

    }
```

Activity is empty: all method overridden just to understand proper Activity lifecycle, but else is empty for now.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = "Activity";
    private Context myContext = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // access a file and get stored information to show

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Application open successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        Log.e(TAG, "----onRestart Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(TAG, "----onSTART Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "----onRESUME Called");

    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "----onPAUSE Called");

    }

    @Override
    protected  void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "----onSTOP Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "----onDestroy Called");


    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated, if you need some more information on the code, I will update the post.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Android system can restart the service if u `return START_STICKY` inside `onStartCommand()`.
- It works perfectly on all lower version than Lollipop in Android.
- No need of CountDownTimer.

Comment: As far as I have tried, START_STIKY and START_REDELIVER_INTENT are sent if the Service is killed while executing. In first case I have to handle a null Intent, in second will redeliver my Intent. Problem is, by redelivering intent, after some start-stopstart-stop sequence are sent, those intent will continue to be sent in order, thus resulting in continuously start and stop the handler every time they are redelivered

Comment: @Giblin van Bauzanum: No matter the reason but if the service is killed then it is restarted by android system.

Comment: I tried with redeliver intent. if activity is closed, after some time, handler starts again. Thanks! But if service is killed in Settings->App->InUse or bay (say) Clean Master, then intent is no more redelivered :(

Comment: @Giblin van Bauzanum: I have check that if u force stop a service then also it gets restarted on pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Hmm strange... after how much should I wait? Because I have waited a lot but doesn't seem to restart (looking at log prints on console)

Comment: @Giblin van Bauzanum: Just try with startHandler() inside onStartCommand(). I'm not sure if the same intent is redelivered. Check by adding a log inside onStartCmnd() or simply toast to see if it gets restarted. Don't w8 more than 5 mins to restart :)

Comment: That's what I'm saying: I have added log in onStartCmnd and there are in handler too but doesn't seem to restart (if it is killed by task manager or clean master)

Comment: @Giblin van Bauzanum: I'll suggest setting repeating an alarm in Activity n checking if service is running or not and then perform necessary actions.